# Android studio: TexView in scrollview disapears on scrolling

Tags: android-layout, scrollview

I have a Scrollview inside a linearLayout that contains a vertical Linearlayout.
there is several text view in it and everything is fine , i can see all views.Until i scroll down . Textviews below the screen  are not showing.
I changed Textview's alpha to .9 and it worked. 
Does anyone know why its like that??
Here is layout.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back1"
    android:alpha="5">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha=".9">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back35"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
                        android:src="@drawable/can_pot_com"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:scaleType="fitStart"
                        android:background="#00ffffff"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3" >

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="گلدان با قوطی کنسرو"
                        android:id="@+id/button6"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:lines="3"
                        android:linksClickable="false"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="#00ffffff"
                         />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back35"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                        android:src="@drawable/alphabete_3d1"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:background="#00ffffff"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="@string/alphabete_3d"
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:lines="3"
                        android:linksClickable="false"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="#00ffffff" />


                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back35"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                        android:src="@drawable/kaghaz_aviz_sample"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:scaleType="fitStart"
                        android:background="#00ffffff"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3" >

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="@string/aviz_kaghazi"
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:lines="3"
                        android:linksClickable="false"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="#00ffffff" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back35"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                        android:src="@drawable/golden_feather_sample"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:scaleType="fitStart"
                        android:background="#00ffffff"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3" >

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="@string/aviz_par_tala"
                        android:id="@+id/button"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:lines="3"
                        android:linksClickable="false"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="#00ffffff" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back35"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_potsample2"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:scaleType="fitStart"
                        android:background="#00ffffff"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3" >

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="@string/botton_pot"
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:lines="3"
                        android:linksClickable="false"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="#00ffffff" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back35"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                        android:src="@drawable/canlendersample"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:scaleType="fitStart"
                        android:background="#00ffffff"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3" >

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="@string/printable_calender"
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:lines="3"
                        android:linksClickable="false"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="#00ffffff" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back35"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:alpha=".9">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                        android:src="@drawable/ballon_pot_sample"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:scaleType="fitStart"
                        android:background="#00ffffff"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3" >

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="@string/ballon_pot"
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:lines="3"
                        android:linksClickable="false"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="#00ffffff"
                        android:alpha="1" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm new to SO if any other thing in necessary pleas let me know.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, Please post code when you are asking any questions so we might have a better idea of what is going on

Comment: @Deepend thank you. i fixed it.